# When to use ng2 Injector.resolveAndCreate vs TypeScript constructor

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I read this [article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dependency-injection) and watched these videos about Dependency Injection in Angular 2:

- [Vojta Jina - Dependency Injection - NG-Conf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OGGsf1ZXMs)
- [Dependency Injection in Angular 2 by Pascal Precht](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZefFBqBncOM)

and quite understand about DI in Angular. But I'm confused on how to use it right.

My question is when to use Type Definition(1) like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
    selector: 'example-component',
    template: '<div>I am a component</div>'
})
class ExampleComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
```

And when to use `Injector`(2) like this:

```
import { Injector, provide } from 'angular2/core'
var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate(
[
provide(SomeObj, {useClass: SomeObj})
]);
```

The second one gets me confused as I'm not sure where it's supposed to go (Component, Service, or else?), how to consume it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to note is that `resolveAndCreate` method is called on `ReflectiveInjector` like this (not `Injector`):

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
const customInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate( ... )
```

The second thing is that `ReflectiveInjector` is deprecated in favor of `StaticInjector`. Read more about it in [Angular deprecates ReflectiveInjector and introduces StaticInjector. Should you care?](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-introduces-staticinjector-should-you-care-4e059eca030c)

So now if you want to create a custom injector you should use `StaticInjector` can do like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
const customInjector = new StaticInjector([
    {provide: `MyCustomToken`, useValue: 'just a string value', deps: [HttpClient]}
])
```

> The second one gets me confused as I'm not sure where it's supposed to
>   go

Custom injectors created using either reflective or static injector can be passed to either module or component factory when instantiating them. Here are some examples from the article [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e):

```
const customInjector = new StaticInjector( ... );

// module
this.loader.load('app/t.module#TModule').then((klass) => {
const factory = compiler.compileModuleSync(klass);
const module = factory.create(customInjector);

// dynamic component
const r = module.componentFactoryResolver;
const cmpFactory = r.resolveComponentFactory(AComponent);
const componentRef = cmpFactory.create(customInjector);
```

Comment: with the (2), should I create custom injector by declaring all classes with `const customInjector = new StaticInjector([...]);` in one file e.g: `DIProvider.ts` and then consume it wherever I need one e.g : `var someObj = customInjector.get(SomeObj);` like this?

Comment: @hngdev, you can create in injector in any file, but probably right there where you need it